# Angular Hottowel 'blocks.exception' and 'blocks.router' Do not Show the App in the Browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hottowel

I've recently picked up on Angular's basics a couple of months ago, and now I'm trying to build an industry-grade-like practice app.

I've just followed John Papa's Play by Play and Clean Code courses on Pluralsight; both are roughly expansions to his latest ng-conf talk. I am yet to read the Style Guide in its entirety but generally, these courses gave me an idea of the what, why and how of many things. There are few things I don't understand in his code, though, which is replicated on the hottowel yo generator. The ['blocks' decorator modules](http://tinyw.in/tvkn), both, 'router' and 'exception' blocks do not work when I try to replicate them into my project. This is what I write to configure my *landing* route (*which is almost exactly what is written in the generator's dashboard route*):

```
(function() {
  'user strict';

  angular
    .module('app.landing')
    .run(appRun);

  appRun.$inject = ['routerHelper'];

  ////////////////////

  // @ngInject
  function appRun(routerHelper) {
    routerHelper.configureStates(getStates());
  }

  function getStates() {
    return [
      {
        state: 'landing',
        config: {
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: 'sections/landing/landing.html',
          controller: 'Landing',
          controllerAs: 'landing',
          title: 'landing'
        }
      }
    ];
  }
})();
```

I am trying to get the app talking to a Rails backend, so I don't want any server-side node implementation (*and my gulp sever is a functioning entirely browser-sync with a middleware proxy implementation*), but even just copying the 'blocks' code to the letter doesn't work with me. It doesn't show anything in the browser, nothing at all in the dev-tools and I lost half of my hair trying to figure out what's wrong.

Could you please help me make sense of this?

Answer (score 0):

depends on what the issue is. is there an error in the dev tools? are the files you show above being loaded in the browser? are you loading the app.landing module? can you set a breakpoint on this code?

Comment: Oh, thank you for the response. It turned out to be mainly a problem of priority. ui-router's compilation of states conflicts with ng-include. But all fixed now. Looking forward to the testing course!